# Convert int array to char array in cpp to give filename

Tags: c++, file

Lets say we have an integer array 1,2,3 (can be up to size 36, so each digit is not a single digit) and I want to name a file as 123...36.txt. I will do this on the go therefore, I need to change filename based on int array values

I checked some solutions online, none of them worked. Is there an easy fix to this? Thanks

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    int i;

    FILE *ptr;

    int b[3]={1,2,3};
    char name[FILENAME_MAX];

    for(i=0;i<3;i++) itoa(b[i],name[i],10);

    name[3]='.';
    name[4]='t';
    name[5]='x';
    name[6]='t';
    name[7]='\0';

    ptr = fopen(name, "w");

    fclose(ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not use a `std::string` object instead of an array of characters?

Comment: I strongly recommend using C++ and `std::string` for the name. If you do that, the easiest way to do this would probably be to iterate over the array, converting the values to a string and appending it to the `std::string name`.

Comment: The second argument to itoa() is a pointer to the buffer where the string will be stored, not a character.

Comment: Remember to stop before reaching the file path length limit for your operating system.

Comment: Why are you using separate `int`s to represent each digit of the number? `int` can represent `123`. You've tagged the question with c++, so use the features c++ provides you. `std::to_string(number) + ".txt";` is all you need.

Comment: I find very low evidence that this is really C++ code, because of the usage of `FILE*`, C-style arrays (including char arrays), a loop index variable initialized outside a loop....

Answer (score 0):

The thing that most resembles your algorithm would be to just use the digits to offset the ascii value of the 0 character. Replace your itoa() line with this:

```
for(i=0;i<3;i++) name[i] = '0'+b[i];
```

This obviously assumes, as your code did, that the incoming int values are between 0 and 9.

Comment: the values can be larger than 9. Therefore thought about it, didnt apply

Comment: Then you need to specify what result you want when they are. Your question as stated (and your attempted solution) both indicate that you expect digits.